How to stop wrist from curling during row?
I notice that when I do rowing motion like pendlay row, then my wrist sometimes curl at top of rep. How can I stop this from happening and keep it straight=?

Wear wrist wraps and/or grip the barbell harder. Gripping harder may resolve it, but it would not be unusual to be able to row enough weight that gripping harder doesn’t help. If you really want to train to be able to maintain a neutral wrist without wraps, training wrist extensions with dumbbells may help. But wraps are the most straightforward solution.
That said, unless it’s causing discomfort, there aren’t really any downsides to have a little bit of wrist flexion at the top of the row, so I wouldn’t worry about it.
